# Using Python and Pandas to Merge Employee Databases with Proxy Emails

Tags: python, pandas, email, merge, proxy

I'm working on a project where I need to get the unique ObjectID of every person in our Microsoft Office tenant and combine it with a table that HR provided me.

```
import pandas as pd

# Imports CSV files
rawexporteddata = pd.read_csv('users_1_13_2021 4_55_49 PM.csv')
hrlist = pd.read_csv('OutlookMasterList.csv')

# Convert email address to lowercase so they'll match the first DF
hrlist['Email Address'].str.lower()

# Merge tables on email/user principle name
merged = hrlist.merge(rawexporteddata, how="left", left_on="Email Address", right_on="User principal name")

merged.to_csv('GettingObjectIDs.csv', index=False)
```

The problem is that many of our users have email aliases that exist on the rawexporteddata data frame in a separate column called "Proxy addresses", and this cell contains a string like "SMTP:george@company.com+smptp:george@othercompany.com+smtp:george@thiscompany.com". Some of these users have a "User principal name" different than the email HR provided, so I'm not getting their unique ObjectID.

I'm thinking that I need some function that would search rawexporteddata['Proxy addresses'] for any instance of "@company.com" and isolate that email address, probably in a new column. I thought maybe a for statement iterating over that column would work, but I'm unsure how to isolate the email address. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you split the column "Proxy address" into new columns using ```rawexporteddata['Proxy addresses'].str.split('+',expand=True)``` and then merge using those as well?

Comment: That's an idea! The only problem with that is the correct email I need to merge on might be in different columns depending on the user. The email I need to merge on doesn't always appear first, so it might appear in the new expanded column A, or in column C for someone else, etc. I think I need to somehow completely remove everything but "blahblah@company.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split "Proxy addresses" by the delimiter and then expand the split into new rows. From here you will have only one column you can use for merging.

```py
# transform Proxy addresses into a list of each email address
rawexporteddata['Proxy addresses'] = rawexporteddata['Proxy addresses'].str.split('+')

# form new rows for each Proxy address
rawexporteddata = rawexporteddata.explode('Proxy addresses')
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! I've never used the explode function; that is very handy! Then I just need to trim the smtp: off the beginning of each string. I should be able to accomplish that with this?

rawexporteddata['Proxy addresses'] = rawexporteddata['Proxy addresses'].str.split(':').str[1]

Comment: Why am I asking when I can just test it? Lol. Yes that works. Thanks again for your help.